# Parallel Sum for Vectors

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

Could someone please provide some suggestions on how I can decrease the following for loop's runtime through multithreading? Suppose I also have two vectors called 'a' and 'b'.

```
for (int j = 0; j < 8000; j++){
    // Perform an operation and store in the vector 'a'
    // Add 'a' to 'b' coefficient wise
}
```

This for loop is executed many times in my program. The two operations in the for loop above are already optimized, but they only run on one core. However, I have 16 cores available and would like to make use of them.

I've tried modifying the loop as follows. Instead of having the vector 'a', I have 16 vectors, and suppose that the i-th one is called a[i]. My for loop now looks like

```
for (int j = 0; j < 500; j++){
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++){
        // Perform an operation and store in the vector 'a[i]'
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++){
        // Add 'a[i]' to 'b' coefficient wise
    }

}
```

I use the OpenMp on each of the for loops inside by adding '#pragma omp parallel for' before each of the inner loops. All of my processors are in use but my runtime only increases significantly. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can decrease the runtime of this loop? Thank You in Advance.

Comment: Have you profiled your code to see where the bottlenecks are?

Comment: it may be because maybe after optimizing you code can't be broken into smaller fragments, if your original for was only doing something like `a[i] += b[i]` then you can add that pragma tag just before that for. it'll boost your performace as you wanted.

Comment: If the body of your loop is really that trivial, then you are probably constrained by the bandwidth of your memory, and more cores will not help (because memory bandwidth is already saturated).  Re-arrange at a higher level to find more work to do inside the loop, or get a machine with faster RAM.

Comment: @GWW, yes, I have profiled my code, and it reports that the most called function is the 1st function in the for loop (that is, performing an operation on the vector). But, as I've said already, this function is already optimized. @Gajet, my original code uses a vector math library, so each of those operations are performed on entire vectors, eg. b += a.

Comment: One more thought.  Forking threads for such trivial operations is unlikely to help.   Make sure your compiler is properly vectorizing your loop.  (If GCC, use -O3.)

Comment: What platform is this on? If it's Windows you might also want to give [the concurrency runtime (aka ConceRT)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504870.aspx) a try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

omp creates threads for your program whereever you insert pragma tag, so it's createing threads for inner tags but the problem is 16 threads are created, each one does 1 operation and then all of them are destroyed using your method. creating and destroying threads take a lot of time so the method you used increases the overal time of your process although it uses all 16 cores. you didn't have to create inner fors just put `#pragma omp parallel for` tag before your 8000 loop it's up to omp to seperate values between treads so what you did to create the second loop, is omp's job. that way omp create threads only once and then process 500 numbers useing that each thread and end all of them after that (using 499 less thread creation and destruction)

Comment: This is my first time using OpenMp, but I do 'omp_set_num_threads(16)' in my main method. Does it not act as a threadpool and not destroy any threads?

Comment: threads are just like functions, you can't add or remove any operation in their list. just think of thread creating function as something that get's a pointer to function as an input. `omp_set_num_threads` by the way is something optional, if you don't put it there omp itself chooses how many threads it should create to optimize your code the most, setting that is only forceing omp to use you amount use specified.

Comment: the [wiki page for omp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP) contains almost all the needed data to create a simple omp program just read it before any debuging you are going to do.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I am going to put these comments in an answer.

Forking threads for trivial operations just adds overhead.

First, make sure your compiler is using vector instructions to implement your loop.  (If it does not know how to do this, you might have to code with vector instructions yourself; try searching for "SSE instrinsics".  But for this sort of simple addition of vectors, automatic vectorization ought to be possible.)

Assuming your compiler is a reasonably modern GCC, invoke it with:

```
gcc -O3 -march=native ...
```

Add `-ftree-vectorizer-verbose=2` to find out whether or not it auto-vectorized your loop and why.

If you are already using vector instructions, then it is possible you are saturating your memory bandwidth.  Modern CPU cores are pretty fast...  If so, you need to restructure at a higher level to get more operations inside each iteration of the loop, finding ways to perform lots of operations on blocks that fit inside the L1 cache.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I do have SSE2 enabled and I'm using microsoft's compiler with the Visual Studio 2010 IDE. I'll take this into consideration and see if I can restructure anything else.

Comment: I suggest running with -S to look at the assembly and make sure it is using SSE2 instructions.

Answer (score 0):

`Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can decrease the runtime of this loop?`

```
for (int j = 0; j < 500; j++){  // outer loop
  for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++){  // inner loop
```

Always try to make **outer loop** iterations lesser than **inner loop**. This will save you from **inner loop initializations** that many times. In above code inner loop `i = 0;` is initialized `500` times. Now,

```
for (int i = 0; j < 16; i++){  // outer loop
  for (int j = 0; j < 500; j++){  // inner loop
```

Now, inner loop `j = 0;` is initialized only 16 times !
Give a try by modifying your code accordingly, if it makes any impact.

Comment: On a modern CPU, this advice is exactly backwards. A sequence of _small_ inner loops is more likely to operate on data in the L1 cache, which is 100-1000 times more important than the overhead of initializing a loop counter.

Comment: @Nemo, thanks, I was unaware of it. However, here you probably you meant *smaller* loop rather than *inner* loop correct ? That will depend on cache size also. If the cache size is really able to accommodate *bigger* loop then, the logic about still sustains.

Comment: Yes.  The key is be cache-friendly, and a typical L1 cache is something like 32K these days.  So you want to make sure your inner loops touch less data than that...